# Qt 5.5 and OpenGL: read access violation exception raised when trying to call paintGL()

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am writing a simple application that uses Qt 5.5 and OpenGL to draw some very basic geometry in a QtOpenGLWidget. Initially, much of the vertex data initialization and rendering code was taken out of a tutorial designed to draw a single triangle. This version worked correctly, but my own attempt at modifying it to facilitate 4 vertices to form a square has underwent without success. The program compiles with no errors, but crashes when executed without even drawing the ui to the screen, with the following error:

```
error: Exception at 0x53fe35, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x0, flags=0x0 (first chance)
```

I am using Qt's OpenGL wrappers everywhere I can.

The first potential (and probable) solution I found is in [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/720651/access-violation-in-nvoglv32-dll-how-do-i-track-down-the-problem-/) post; the problem in question has an identical error signature, and the description of the cause of the problem, that being incorrectly enabled or configured VAO's, also seems considerable to my case, considering the addition of another vertex to the VBO and my likely ineptitude to correctly reconfigure the glVertexAttribPointer. I cannot, however, find the problem in my code.

GLWidget's (the OpenGL widget in question) declaration:

```
class GLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions {
    Q_OBJECT

    void prepareVertexBuffers();

    void prepareVertexShader();
    void prepareFragmentShader();
    void prepareShaderProgram();

    void applyShaderPrograms();

    QOpenGLBuffer *vertBuffer;
    QOpenGLBuffer *elementBuffer;
    QOpenGLVertexArrayObject *vao;

    QOpenGLShader *vertShader;
    QOpenGLShader *fragShader;
    QOpenGLShaderProgram *shaderProgram;

public:
    GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL();
    void paintGL();

signals:
    void shaderCompiled(const QString compilationLog);

public slots:
    void updateFragmentShader(QString newsource);
};
```

prepareVertexBuffers() function - here I define 4 vertices and arrange them into 2 triangles to form a square.

```
void GLWidget::prepareVertexBuffers() {

    static const GLfloat vertData[] = {
       -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
       -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
       1.0f,  -1.0f, 0.0f,
       1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    };

    static const GLushort elementData[] = {1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4};

    vao = new QOpenGLVertexArrayObject(this);
    vao->create();
    vao->bind();

    vertBuffer = new QOpenGLBuffer(QOpenGLBuffer::VertexBuffer);
    vertBuffer->create();
    vertBuffer->allocate(vertData, 4 * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat) );
    vertBuffer->setUsagePattern( QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw );
    vertBuffer->bind();

    elementBuffer = new QOpenGLBuffer(QOpenGLBuffer::IndexBuffer);
    elementBuffer->create();
    elementBuffer->allocate(elementData, 6 * sizeof(GLushort) );
    elementBuffer->setUsagePattern( QOpenGLBuffer::StaticRead );
    elementBuffer->bind();
}
```

paintGL(), where I suspect the problem is:

```
void GLWidget::paintGL() {
    vao->bind();
    vertBuffer->bind();
    elementBuffer->bind();

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3, (void*)0 );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 4);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    elementBuffer->release();
    vertBuffer->release();
    vao->release();
}
```

It is obvious to note that I have virtually no experience in using OpenGL, and so clues as to how to structure my code correctly and general coding practices would also be appreciated.

Comment: There are lots of weird things in your code: your element indices should be 0-based, the usage hint `StaticRead` for the element buffer doesn't make sense, you are not even _using_ that element array at all, you use DrawArrays with a count of 4 vertices, which should just generate a triangle with the first 3 vertices, and ignore the 4th because it can't built a triangle with just one vertex. However, none of these errors should trigger a crash.

Comment: where are you calling `prepareVertexBuffers`? If it happens without a OpenGL context being available and bound it will do nothing. Regarding Qt the only valid places to use OpenGL functions are within the `…GL` methods (`initializeGL`, `paintGL`, `resizeGL`) or when manually using `makeCurrent`…`doneCurrent`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks derhass for some clarification. I blindly assumed that glDrawArrays magically uses the currently bound element buffer to draw - evidently it is not so. I change the line

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 4);
```

to

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

and the program no longer crashes on startup.

Furthermore, I made sure to bind() the buffers before allocating memory to them as per the documentation.

Comment: But that still doesn't make sense. The `glDrawArrays` call might not have been what you wanted, but it shouldn't have crashed in this constellation.

Comment: @derhass: Constellation? @MaxB: That's still not right, the thing you are passing in the place of `elementBuffer` is supposed to be an integer offset into the address space of that buffer -- the location in its memory where the first element is found. You appear to be passing a pointer to an object that encapsulates that buffer (which the API allows since it takes a `GLvoid*`); it's allowed, but meaningless to do that.

Comment: @Andon: I looked at the documentation at https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDrawElements.xhtml and I am confused - the last parameter is GLvoid * indices - is this an actual pointer to memory or an internal "integer" openGL pointer? is so, should I be passing the return value of bufferID() of the elementBuffer?

Comment: @MaxB: When a non-zero value is bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY` (this is what `elementBuffer->bind (...)` does for you; `->release (...)` binds **0**), the value passed at the end of this function is interpreted as an offset into the bound array's memory (server-side / driver managed memory). If **0** is bound, it is a pointer to client-side (your application's) memory. _It's kind of both thanks to buffer objects being an afterthought in the OpenGL API - they modified the behavior of existing API functions when vertex buffers were introduced._ Pass **0** for the address, more than likely.

Comment: @Andon: I see. Setting the value to 0 now got something to show up. But why? surely my elementBuffer instance, when bound, is not located in client-side memory (address "0") but somewhere in the Driver managed space? I would have thought that perhaps using the function "bufferID()" would return the 'address', but it seems like it is used for another purpose. Edit: worth noting I also made sure that I bound the buffers before allocating data to them now.

Comment: @MaxB: No, I think you still are not understanding. When an element buffer is bound, the address passed to `glDrawElements (...)` is relative to the beginning of that buffer's memory. If you want to point to the first element in that buffer, for example, the address is **0**. If you have no element buffer bound when making the call, then `glDrawElements (...)` actually takes the pointer you pass it and tries to dereference it as you would any standard pointer in C. The memory pool that the pointer is relative to is basically what changes depending on which buffer object is bound.

Comment: @MaxB: I looked at the API documentation and I can see why you might be a little confused, I would like to point you [here](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.compatibility.pdf#page=394). Focus on the text in red, it illustrates optional behavior that exists in a compatibility profile. I don't know what kind of profile you have, in core it's pretty much assumed that the pointer is always related to a buffer object, in compatibility it may be to client-side memory.

Comment: @Andon: Thanks for taking the time to explain this, I was over-complicating it. I think I understand now - the last parameter in glDrawElements() is simply an offset from where to begin reading the currently bound element array.